# Is Making use of an electrical item that someone has disposed of for recycling haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I work within a company which offers members of the public to dispose of their product in a environmental friendly way (recycling). occasionally you encounter items which are in perfect working order, so is it haram to make personal use of such items (as in becoming the new owner of the product), I would have asked the previous owner but i was not present when they have disposed of it!

Many thanks to all muslim brothers and sisters in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you had the chance to tell them that this is working would you do it? Yes!
Did you trick them into throwing it away? No!

And I have never ever seen any person having a claim on trash!
So basically what is in trash belongs to no one. 
Whoever who catches it first owns it! There is an Arabic saying الفضل للمتقدم meaning advantage is given to one who was there first in your case... you being the one who takes it out first.( as there a religious edict that if a person has been selling at a specific point of the bazaar for the past 3 years/days...then he has a right to continue selling there and others can't come and just say hey move away)

**Yet** if by any chance the owners comes and finds the device and says I want it... I do think you have an obligation to give it back...but that's one in a million!